# EasyGui fileopenbox() Error. Has TKinter Changed? [Python]

Tags: python, tkinter, easygui

Keeping it relatively simple. I'm trying to open a fileopenbox to select a file using easygui.

```
easygui.fileopenbox()
```

And easyGUI throws this error

```
'module' object has no attribute 'askopenfilename'
```

The Stack Trace

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.py", line 377, in <module>
    easygui.fileopenbox()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\easygui\boxes\fileopen_box.py", line 103, in fileopenbox
    func = ut.tk_FileDialog.askopenfilenames if multiple else ut.tk_FileDialog.askopenfilename
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'askopenfilename'
```

Whats going on here?

Nothings changed on my system at all, but it almost looks like for some reason python cant find this tkInter function.

Has anyone come across this?
Thanks!

Edit: An additional screenshot showing that the method is not found

https://gyazo.com/8b9ba0f6c23561d13babe7ce4c8b67a1

Comment: installed that package easygui. you can download from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/easygui

Comment: I've been getting exactly the same error ...

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling your `Easygui` and install latest one.
Also try update `Python` version.